# How Can I Encrypte a PDF file in Node js and Decrypt and view a PDF file only with My React Native Application?

Tags: node.js, react-native, pdf, encryption

I am Challenging To encrypt a pdf and show it to users who buy it and they can view it only with application and they wont be able to view that without application.
How can i Manage it ?

Comment: There is no fool-proof way to secure something so it's perfectly safe. For instance, an user can screenshot every page of your PDF while viewing it in the viewer (or, more likely, use a debugger to get at the decrypted PDF as your app processes it for viewing). What is your threat model?

Comment: ahaha you are right @AKX but i want to prevent them from sending pdf books ,

Comment: Again, there is no foolproof method here. So if you _do_ have a password-protected file you can only view with your own viewer, what's preventing an user from sending the file _and_ the password to someone else? If that'll be a problem, you'll need a licensing server of some sort to see which people are using which passwords and from where, etc.

Comment: that wont be a password protected file it will be an encrypted file which user who want to view that they need to have my application and through it they will be able to view the file, ONLY AND ONLY WITH MY APPLICATION

Comment: Okay. What's preventing the users from sending the file and your application to their friends?

Comment: the files will be encrypted and decyprted  when a user buy it with their own id's so the file is enrypted diffrently for all the user's , that is the logic

Comment: How would your app know how to decrypt a file that's encrypted differently for each user? Will each user also get a custom copy of the viewer app?

Comment: with user's id , its simple, we can use the id to decrypt it again.

Comment: So, the user gets an app, a file encrypted with their unique ID, and knows their unique ID. Why can't they pass all of this on to someone else, and this someone else can use it all the same?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can easily handle it with qpdf nodejs and run it through `exec()` 
install qpdf globally then import exec from built-in child_precess i hope it helps 
 `var exec = require('child_process').exec;`

```
var cmd = `qpdf --encrypt ${pass} ${pass} 40 -- ${path.join(path.dirname(__dirname),bookf.pdfUrl)} ${path.join(path.dirname(__dirname),encryptedUrl)}`;


exec(cmd, function (err){
 if (err){
console.error('Error occured: ' + err);
  }else{                                      
    console.log('PDF encrypted :)');
    res.status(201).json({
    message:result,
    isNewBook:true
            })
```

Comment: thank you sooooo much it helped me so much it saved my life

Comment: and i recommend you to read the nodejs docs for working  with builtin libraries

Comment: So... whoever receives the PDF can just share it, and the password they receive. Or call qpdf --decrypt to get the original...

Comment: the passeord can be saved in the database , and you can put some authorization for that.

Comment: i mean you wont give the password directly to the users!,,, some logic like verification system can be used here